# exception handling not working within with open python

Tags: python, exception, python-3.6

I am a new bee to python . I have to run this python code as part of robot automation framework . I have two challenges

1. I need to read the file through regex if the string in file matches pass , which is working for me . However since a lot of lines are also not matching it is showing fail for me as well
2. I am try to use exception handling as I need to inform Robot framework to Fail this test case if string is not found .

Unfortunately I wrote my snippets in many ways but my code will simply not work

```
code 1:

with open("C:/Users/diwak/Desktop/1.txt", "r") as a1:
    for line in a1:
        b = re.search('loopback4 is up, line protocol is up',line)
        if b:
            print ('found')
        else:
            print ("not found") -----> first issue displays all failed lines , i dont want this and second robot script simply passes as no  exception was used here
```

code2:

```
import os
import re


with open("C:/Users/diwak/Desktop/1.txt", "r") as a1:
    for line in a1:
        b = re.search('loopback4 is up, line protocol is up',line)
        if b:
            print ('found')
        else:
            raise Exception ("not found") # if above line is not found robot is informed that test case is failed which is ok , but program exits midway without running further which i dont want
```

> output of 1:
>
> python script says:
>
> b not found not found not found
>
> Robot script :
>
> simple says "PASS"
>
> output 2:
>
> python script:  not found
>
> Robot script  failed successfully  but next code is not executed

Kindly help

Comment: what do you mean with first requirement? what does 'pass' mean? can you provide a few line of text?

Comment: can you help with the code atleast , let me simplify it a lot :

Comment: why my exception is not working here:

Comment: import os
import re

with open("C:/Users/diwak/Desktop/1.txt", "r") as a1:
    for line in a1:
        b = re.search('loopback4 is up, line protocol is up',line)
        if b:
            try:
                print ('Found')
            except:
                print ("not found")

Comment: `Execption` cause the script to stop totally. it's not appropriate for a API. please let us know... if there is just one line in the text file that match, whats going to happen?

Comment: yes its just one line man